# Stargazer: how to remove R-squared using Python

Tags: python, stargazer

I am using Stargazer to combine the regression result tables and want to remove R-squared and adjusted R-squared rows. While there is `omit.stat=c("f", "rsq")` in R, I am wondering if there is any similar method in Python codes? I have looked into some references like https://pypi.org/project/stargazer/ for a list of the methods/features but did not find any.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "I have looked into some references ... for a list of the methods/features but did not find any" - if this list is indeed exhaustive, then this library doesn't provide such an option

Answer (score 0):

For a Stargazer object `stargazer` just do.

```
stargazer.show_r2 = False
```

Same applies for `show_n`, `show_adj_r2`, `show_residual_std_err` and `show_f_statistic`